# Is Apple breaking MVC rules in MailboxContentViewCell.h on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

According to MVC rules, V stands for views, and M stands for data. Strict MVC forbids V to access M directly just like http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tISOU011t_U/T1yDocALTUI/AAAAAAAAAII/AFiwMAr-Z6g/s640/MVC+Obj-C.png shows, right?
I was reverse engineering MobileMail i.e. the Mail App on iOS 8, and have noticed that inside MailboxContentViewCell.h, there was a - (MFMailMessage *)message method. If I'm understanding MVC correctly, MailboxContentViewCell is a V and MFMailMessage is an M, V reads M directly, which breaks the MVC rules. So, is it my misunderstanding of MVC, or Apple breaks MVC indeed in this case?

Comment: That could also be seen as a Data Transfer Object or a View Model class. The real M is probably the code that handles the on-disk storage of the mail database and its interaction with the mail server.

Comment: @Thilo In my understanding of MVC, M is not just one single class, so MFMailMessage belongs to M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC is **not** a rule. It is a **pattern**. It's less a rule than a design philosophy and a set of guidelines. In practice most nontrivial apps are unlikely to adopt a pure, unsullied MVC a design, even when MVC *is* the primary design pattern. Sometimes it's just not a good fit. Sometimes it is a good fit but schedule requirements mean that idealism has to be sacrificed in order to ship something.

So, is Apple violating MVC here? I don't know but it wouldn't surprise me a bit. Nor would it seem especially troubling if they are.

Comment: I agree with you that 100% MVC is too good to be true, but I still wonder is Apple really breaking MVC in this case? Or it's my misunderstanding of MVC?

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without getting at their source code. Probably yes, but so what?

Comment: Just to make sure if it's a misunderstanding of MVC